# split a string representation with ranges into a list of dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have this pandas dataframe column with timeranges (02.07.2021  - 07.07.2021 ) and single days (04.08.2021) as a list.

| Dates |
| --- |
| '02.07.2021 - 07.07.2021 , 04.08.2021, 19.06.2021 - 21.06.2021' |
| '13.02.2021 - 15.02.2021 , 03.03.2021 ' |
| NaN |
| NaN |

I want this:

| Dates |
| --- |
| 02.07.2021, 03.07.2021, 04.07.2021, 05.07.2021, 06.07.2021, 07.07.2021, 04.08.2021, 19.06.2021, 20.06.2021, 21.06.2021 |
| 13.02.2021, 14.02.2021, 15.02.2021, 03.03.2021 |
| NaN |
| NaN |

So basically I want every day within every time range in a list.

Is there a pandas solution for that? (I've tried to solve it with range and iloc but this is way to mucht for this "simple" task).

Bonus: The dates should have the datetime dytpe (`pd.to_datetime()`)

Comment: can you provide your input and output as DataFrame constructors for explicitness? `df.to_dict()` if you already have the object

Comment: input:
d = {'02.07.2021 - 07.07.2021 , 04.08.2021, 19.06.2021 - 21.06.2021'}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

Comment: output: 

d = {'02.07.2021, 03.07.2021, 04.07.2021, 05.07.2021, 06.07.2021, 07.07.2021, 04.08.2021, 19.06.2021, 20.06.2021, 21.06.2021'}

but should be a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
pd.Series([[str(d.strftime('%d.%m.%Y'))
            for x in re.split('\s*,\s*', s)
            for d in (pd.date_range(*map(lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d, format='%d.%m.%Y'),
                                         x.split(' - ')),
                                    freq='D')
              if ' - ' in x else [pd.to_datetime(x.strip(), format='%d.%m.%Y')])]
            for s in df['Dates']])
```

output:

```
0    [02.07.2021, 03.07.2021, 04.07.2021, 05.07.202...
1     [13.02.2021, 14.02.2021, 15.02.2021, 03.03.2021]
dtype: object
```

Used input:

```
d = ['02.07.2021 - 07.07.2021 , 04.08.2021, 19.06.2021 - 21.06.2021',
     '13.02.2021 - 15.02.2021 , 03.03.2021 ']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': d})
```

Comment: Thank you! But in my case all single days are excluded (in the first row = 04.08.2021 and in the second = 03.03.2021)

Comment: strange, it works for me, I have them. I added my input for reproducibility.

Comment: ok I guess, I had an error in my input. This works! Thanks!

Comment: @danielguo you might want to slice the non NaN row to apply the transformation only to those (I haven't tested NaNs)

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but I've tried it with another input:

d = ['13.02.2021  - 13.02.2021 , 19.06.2021  - 19.06.2021 '] 

and got an error: unconverted data remains

Comment: Try `x.strip().split(' - ')` in place of `x.split(' - ')`, I believe the extra spaces are messing up

Comment: I hadn't seen that you would like to have datetime type, just remove the `.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')`